# Using cmd as a compiler to execute cpp files

Tags: c++, cmd, command-line

I am an absolute beginner and starting to learn c++. Most people use an IDE to execute files. But in my book, it tells to use command prompt to execute the CPP files. But when I type gcc it tells me it is not recognized.

Also, What is the benefit of using the compiler over IDE? Where I can find the commands to execute files and how do I access my file program files stored within my PC. How does it all works.

Comment: ***I type gcc it tells me it is not recognized*** Did you install mingw? Did you set it to add an entry in your windows PATH environment variable so that the executable is in a folder that your OS will look?

Comment: ***What is the benefit of using the compiler over IDE?*** Its much simpler. And does not require you to understand a bunch of documentation about your compiler and also does not require that you have a large understanding of how the command line works works on your OS. Also an IDE usually has a built in debugger.  Learning out how to effectively use a debugger is an essential skill to know. You will not be a successful programmer without mastering it.

Comment: Yes, I did install MinGW and used Environmental Variable to set path

Comment: If you rebooted, then some part of that setup failed.

Comment: The problem is that people, including those who wrote your book, and most man pages, sites, and answers you'll get here, are lazy. They expect you to have modified your system in order to prevent you from having to type more characters. There is no need to modify the `PATH` environment variable, and certainly no need to install additional utilities in order to run your command. The correct way to run your commannd is to use `"C:\Path\To\gcc.exe"`, instead of `gcc`. _(obviously adjusting `C:\Path\To\ ` according to the location holding your specifc executable utility.)_

Answer (score 2):

So the IDE uses a compiler as well, the IDE just wraps it in an easy to use graphical interface. If you are an absolute beginner I would recommend using an IDE over a compiler. Maybe consider Code Blocks. This is a good video on how to setup code blocks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWJqsmitR2I
You should be able to run anything you want from the book on code blocks and the compiler.

Also the reason it says you dont have gcc is because you need to install it first, and then add the application to the path environment variables. Look up "instlling gcc " for your platform of choice.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to execute a cpp file:

cpp files are files, written in C++ language. That is a human programming language, which enables people to order computers to do something. However: computers don't understand cpp files, they only understand executable files (exe files in a Windows environment). Therefore, the cpp file(s) must be translated into an executable file. This is called "compiling" and the result of that compilation (as that action is called) can be executed.

When you are using an IDE (an Integrated Development Environment), both actions (compile and execute) might be merged (you might see "Run", which is in fact a compilation, followed by a "Run").

So, if you want to do all this, you WILL need to perform two actions.

Does this mean that commandline is out of the question, when launching C++ programs? No, not at all, it's even very interesting to see what's happening behind the scenes. But, first of all, I would advise you to start doing some simple programming, using the IDE, launch some simple programs, and then see (most IDEs have so-called "console" or "output" windows where you can see the commandline commands).

Answer (score 0):

GCC is a program, that must be installed before you can use it. Follow the instructions in your book, or see [here](https://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/).

All programs need to be compiled with a compiler. An IDE just automates the process and makes it easier to use. There are several reasons to use the command-liner directly:

- Less software to install
- You have a more close-up view of what is happening under the hood
- Advanced programmers have more control over various compilation options

Answer (score -2):

`cmd` is not a compiler. It is a command-prompt that allows you to run programs on your computer. GCC is a compiler, and also a program. You have to install it before you can use it.

An IDE just kinda does the "typing in `cmd`" bit for you.